# SSRS says people that have access to a report don't have sufficient permissions to view the report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I want to grant people access to.  There are three people I want to be able to see this report: myself and two co-workers.  The security has been set up like so:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators Content Manager 
<domain>\User 1 Browser 
<domain>\User 2 Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder 
<domain>\Me     Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder
```

Myself and user 2 have the exact same roles.  But I am the only one that can see the reports.  Everyone else gets this:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The permissions granted to user '<domain>\User 1' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

I don't understand how the other users can't access this report.  Has anyone encountered this type of thing before?

Comment: Are you seeing that error when browsing for a report in Report Manager, or when you actually try and run a report?

Comment: When we try to run the report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the problem was the reports in question used shared datasets, so I had to grant permission to the datasets and datasources folders in Report Manager so the reports could then be viewed.